# Why is my collection info geometry node not referencing all of it's objects?

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections

I'm fairly new to blender and am doing blender guru's donut tutorial. I have gotten to the part where you make a collection of sprinkles and reference that instead of a single object. However, even though all of my sprinkle variations are in the same collection, only two of them are being used in the viewport. I have no idea if this is something I did. The picture shows all of the nodes I have placed and the viewport.
[image]

Here is the blender file separately if needed.

[image]

Comment: You setup looks fine at first glance. It might be something like some of your sprinkle objects having their origin points at an offset (https://i.imgur.com/ZS6iN2l.png) so they're *inside* the donut, for example: https://i.imgur.com/UxyeVtt.png Is that it? If not, maybe share your file with us so we can take a look. You can use blend-exchange.com

Comment: I thought about the origin points as well but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I attached the blender file if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we assign different colors to your sprinkles we can see that they *are* being picked as instances. The trouble here is that you probably produced some of them just by scaling another, but haven't *applied* their scale yet, so Geometry Nodes is presenting them in their real/original dimensions:

[image]

You can apply their scales via the *Object* > *Apply* menu (<kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd>) > *Scale*:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Are you able to apply the scale of multiple objects at once?

Comment: @Bobinator Yes, you are.

Comment: I see. I believe I accidentally deselected two of them when I was applying the scale. Thank you for your help.